# node.js dotenv load is not a function

Tags: node.js, dotenv

i just updated my packages and im unable to load in my env file using the npm dotenv package.

> "dotenv": "^7.0.0", "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.0",

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";

    switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
            case "test":
                break;
            case "production":
                break;
            default:
                dotenv.load({ path: ".env" });
        }
```

> "error":{},"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException:
>   dotenv_1.default.load is not a function\nTypeError:
>   dotenv_1.default.load is not a function

Comment: Because `load` is not a function : https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @Seblor yep its been removed in the new version

Answer (score 2):

dotenv npm library does not have a `load` parameter, what you are trying to do would require you use `.config` instead

```
dotenv.config({ path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/env/vars' })
```